# RelativeLayout element disappearing

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a strange problem with RelativeLayout. I have 3 elements and one is always missing - I can't event see it in Android Device Monitor in UI snapshot - it's not in view tree. What is strange, LinearLayout which lays to right of my missing View has some margin from left in size of this missing view width. Here is my XML. The missing view is `t_product_indicator`.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="left"
android:background="@drawable/list_item_background">

<View
    android:id="@+id/t_product_indicator"
    android:layout_width="4dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/t_product_details_container"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/t_product_indicator"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/t_product_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerInside" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/t_product_image_progress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"/>
    </FrameLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/t_product_kod"
                style="@style/product_bold"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="70R201"
                android:textAllCaps="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/t_product_nazwa_short"
                style="@style/product_bold"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:lines="1"
                android:text="NEO-TOOLS" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/t_product_nazwa"
                style="@style/product_normal"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:lines="1"
                android:text="Torba monterska skórzana, (LxWxH) 43 x 17 x 27 cm, masa 2.5 kg"
                android:textAllCaps="false" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/t_product_ilosc"
                style="@style/product_normal"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:lines="1"
                android:text="112 szt." />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/t_product_status"
                style="@style/product_normal"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:lines="1"
                android:text="Do wycofania (DW)" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/t_product_cena"
                style="@style/product_normal"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:lines="1"
                android:text="365,55 PLN" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1px"
    android:layout_below="@+id/t_product_details_container"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:background="@color/form_section_title" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Anyone has some idea why this View is invisible ?

**Solution I've tried and are not working**

1.

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/t_product_indicator"
    android:layout_width="4dp"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

2.

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/t_product_indicator"
    android:layout_width="4dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
```

3.

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/t_product_indicator"
    android:layout_width="4dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
```

4.

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/t_product_indicator"
    android:layout_width="4dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

Comment: PS. This layout is row layout for RecyclerView but I don't think it has something to do with my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution myself.

I just have to adjust indicator height to LinearLayout to right of it. So I've just add alignTop and alignBottom to `t_product_details_container` and everything works fine now !

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/t_product_indicator"
    android:layout_width="4dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/t_product_details_container"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/t_product_details_container"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
```

Comment: Good to hear .Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing to set **android:layout_height="Your_value dp"**

For testing , Set `android:layout_height="2dp"` instead `android:layout_height="0dp"`

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/t_product_indicator"
    android:layout_width="4dp"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

### Edited

```
<View
android:id="@+id/t_product_indicator"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
```

Comment: When I set 2dp I can only see a little square at bottom-left (2dp tall). I want this view to fill entire left part of row. I also tried to set height to match_parent but it has same effect as 0dp - View is invisible.

Comment: @PawelUrban did you set android:layout_width="fill_parent"

Comment: Why would I set width to fill_parent ? I want it width to be 4dp as I have in XML. I want it to have height equal to parent ?

Comment: `fill_parent` is **deprecated**. Please use `match_parent`

Answer (score 0):

add height to`t_product_indicator` view  as per your requirement currently its `0dp` also you have added attributes

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

if you want to keep view's height minimum then  remove either `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` or  `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` as its misleading

EDIT

try this

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/t_product_indicator"
    android:layout_width="4dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
```

Comment: I want this indicator to fill entire left part of row with 4dp height - something like this : http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61UhM7f2aNL.png

Comment: @PawelUrban check my Edit

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your code with this and tell me if there's still some problem,

```
    <View
        android:id="@+id/t_product_indicator"
        android:layout_width="4dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
```